# Function to check for NULL and concatenating the strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, isnull

I have a SQL statement that concatenates **First Name** and **Last Name** of the person. I use the following SQL statement.

```
ISNULL(FullName.FirstName, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(FullName.LastName, '')
```

What I need is to change this to add the `FirstName` and `LastName` only if they are not both `NULL`. If one of them is not NULL, use that value.

Examples:

1. FirstName and LastName are NULL -> NULL
2. FirstName is John and LastName is NULL -> John
3. FirstName is NULL and LastName is Doe -> Doe

-> indicates the result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use CONCAT() to concatenate without any NULL issues
- TRIM() to remove any spaces for when one or both fields are missing
- NULLIF() to replace '' with NULL if first and last name are both
  missing

### SQL Server 2017+ Solution

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #emp
CREATE TABLE #emp (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25));
    
INSERT INTO #emp 
VALUES(null,null)
,('John',null)
,('Doe',null)
,('John', 'Doe');

SELECT FullName = NULLIF(TRIM(CONCAT(FirstName,' ',LastName)),'')
    ,*
FROM #emp
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you just wrap you current expression inside `TRIM()` it should give you the behavior you want:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(ISNULL(FullName.FirstName, '') + ' ' +
            ISNULL(FullName.LastName, '')) AS FullName
FROM yourTable;
```

In the event that only the first or last name be present, your original expression would leave a dangling leading/trailing space.  The call to `TRIM()` fixes that by removing this extra space.

Comment: Is it possible to return ```NULL``` instead of an empty string? If ```FirstName``` is ```NULL``` and ```LastName``` is ```NULL```, the result should return a ```NULL```.

Comment: @wonderfulworld What is your actual database.  If you're using Oracle, my answer as stated above would already yield `NULL` when both first and last name be missing.  Based on what you tell me, I can update my answer.

Comment: I use MS SQL. I tried your suggestion, but the query does not return ```NULL```.

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple case statement to solve this:

```
    create table emp (emp_id int4, fname varchar(10), lname varchar(10));
    
    insert into emp (emp_id) values(1);
    insert into emp (emp_id,fname) values(2, 'John');
    insert into emp (emp_id,lname) values(3, 'Doe');
    insert into emp (emp_id,fname,lname) values(4, 'John', 'Doe');
    
    
    select emp_id,fname, lname, 
    case 
        WHEN FNAME is not null and LNAME is not null then 
            FNAME||' '||LNAME
        WHEN FNAME is not null and LNAME is NULL then 
            FNAME
        WHEN FNAME is null and LNAME is not NULL then 
            LNAME
        else null
        end as FULL_NAME
    from emp;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### A better SQL Server 2017 solution:

**Use the new `CONCAT_WS` function**, which concatenates with a separator, ignoring nulls

```sql
CREATE TABLE #emp (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), FirstName VARCHAR(25), LastName VARCHAR(25));
    
INSERT INTO #emp 
VALUES(null,null)
,('John',null)
,('Doe',null)
,('John', 'Doe');

SELECT FullName = CONCAT_WS(' ', FirstName, LastName)
    ,*
FROM #emp;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1f343bfdcb953ee51201348e95b9af53)